# xsl:if that depends on a child node

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

I have this bookmap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bookmap>
<part>
    <chapter/>
    <chapter/>
    <chapter/>
</part>
<part/>
<part/>
<part/>
<part/>
<appendix/>
</bookmap>
```

I would like to place inside templates, xsl:if commands that depend on whether elements are `part/chapter` or `part`.

I.e. I had these inside the template `processTopicTitle`, part of the DITA-OT distribution:

```
<xsl:if test="bookmap/part/chapter">
    <fo:external-graphic src="thisischapter.png" />
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="bookmap/part">
    <fo:external-graphic src="thisispart.png" />
</xsl:if>
```

This is not working.

The idea is that the there is a graphic that shows up only in **part/chapters**, and another on the ones that are only **part**.

Comment: It is possibly "not working" as your context would need to be the document node for the test to return true. It would probably help to see more of your XSLT to give a fuller answer, especially the template the statements the statements are in. Could you also edit your question to show your expected output? Thank you.

Comment: Here is the section where I want to put the diamond.png: (http://josecotes.com/tmp/sample1.txt)

I am trying to put that graphic before the title of each topic, but just for the topics that are inside a *part* only. The ones that are inside *chapter* will not have that graphic added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work like this:

```
<xsl:template name="insertDiamond">
    <xsl:variable name="topicref" select="key('map-id', ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class,' topic/topic ')][1]/@id)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$topicref//ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/part ')][not(child::*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/chapter ')])]">
            <!--Put actions here for parts without any chapters as childs-->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!--Put actions here for the rest.-->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is something like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <!-- parts -->
    <xsl:when test="$map//*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/part ')]">
        <xsl:call-template name="getVariable">
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'First Cover Image Path'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <!-- chapters -->
    <xsl:when test="$map//*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/chapter ')]">
        <xsl:call-template name="getVariable">
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'Second Cover Image Path'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <!-- parts without chapters -->
    <xsl:when test="$map//*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/part ')][not(child::*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/chapter ')])">
        <xsl:call-template name="getVariable">
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="'Third Cover Image Path'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

You should define images in the config files `~/cfg/common/vars/en.xml`

You should read:

- [Overriding an XSLT-processing step](http://www.dita-ot.org/dev/dev_ref/plugin-overridestyle.html)
- [Modifying or adding generated text > Example: adding new strings](http://www.dita-ot.org/dev/dev_ref/plugin-addgeneratedtext.html)

**Update**

To place your image, you should use the `placeImage` template:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="placeImage" select=".">
    <xsl:with-param name="imageAlign" select="@align"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="href"
                    select="
                    if (@scope = 'external' or opentopic-func:isAbsolute(@href)) then
                        @href
                    else
                        concat($input.dir.url, @href)"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="height" select="@height"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="width" select="@width"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

It is helpful to generate a plugin using the [dita-generator](http://dita-generator.elovirta.com), set a custom cover image and then compare your code with the code of the generated plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately it did not work as expected. Here is the link of the section http://josecotes.com/tmp/sample1.txt. 

Right now I added these but still not working:
      `<xsl:if test="$map//*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/part ')][not(child::*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/chapter ')])">
                            <fo:external-graphic src="./Customization/OpenTopic/common/artwork/diamond.png" content-height="20px" scaling="uniform" />
                            <fo:inline>&#xA0;&#xA0;</fo:inline>
                    </xsl:if>`

Comment: I added an example how to use the placeImage template. Could you please explain what does not work?

Comment: I was testing this further... in your first piece of code above, all of them return true. The first `<ssl:when>` in the `<xsl:choose>` list is triggered. The I deleted that one and then the second was true and so on.